# Time Complexity of Recursive Algorithm Array

Tags: algorithm, performance, math, recursion, time-complexity

I have a recursive algorithm like that which computes the smallest integer in the array.

```
 ALGORITHM F_min1(A[0..n-1])
//Input: An array A[0..n-1] of real numbers
If n = 1
return A[0]
else
temp ← F_minl(A[0..n-2])
If temp ≤ A[n-1]
return temp
else
return A[n-1]
```

What I think that the reccurence relation should be

T(n)=T(n-1) + n

However I am not sure about the `+ n` part. I want to be sure in which cases the recurrence is `T(n)=T(n-1) + 1` and in which cases the recurrence is  `T(n)=T(n-1) + n`.

Comment: Its *T(n)=T(n-1) + 1* so it's Theta(n) globally. At least, at first glance. Where "+1" is an umbrella term to indicate a finite set of constant time operations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The recurrence should be

```
T(1) = 1,
T(n) = T(n-1) + 1
```

because besides the recursive call to the smaller array, all computational effort (reading the last entry of `A` and doing the comparison) take constant time in unit cost measure. The algorithm can be understood as *divide-and-conquer* where the *divide part* is splitting the array into a prefix and the last entry; the *conquer part*, which is a comparison, cannot take more than constant time here. In total, a case where there is linear work  after the recursive call does not exist.

Comment: Thank you very much, what I tought is that after the recursion there will be n comparions so o(n).

Comment: @ayt_cem Indeed, there are `n` comparisons _in total_; however, there is only one comparison in each recursive call.

Comment: So in order to be + o(n) in each comparison after the recursive call, there should be n comparisons ?

Comment: Yes, but there is only one.